# Don't clutter half the screen with things most people don't care for

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, user-experience, anonymous-user

TL;DR: Stack Exchange has a principle: the advertising is minimal, and shouldn't interfere with the contents of the sites. This works for all sites except Stack Overflow. Please fix this. Details below.

---

Today I happened to use Guest mode of my browser to search for something, got results from Stack Overflow, and was totally aghast when I saw this:

> [image]

All I wanted was to read the question and its answers. After all, that's what Stack Overflow should be: Q&A site. But it's not. Not really, with the question and answers buried so deep.

Putting on my Visitor Hat, here is what I was thinking:

1. I don't care about any Salary Calculator. If I would care for new shiny stuff in Stack Overflow, I can just click the bold orange "NEW" icon. Don't shove this into my unwilling face.
2. I don't want to log in or create account. Just read the answers. Don't shove this ***HUGE***, ***ENORMOUS***, login dialog right there on half the page. It's distracting.
3. I don't really care that Stack Overflow got over 50 million visitors per month. It's nice and awesome for Stack Overflow, but I am only one visitor who need to read something, and that self advertisement is hiding what I need. If I care how many others also visit, I'll find some "About Us" link and go there.

This is worse than advertisements. This is a terrible User Experience; the worst I've seen to be honest. No other site pushes so much useless content on each and every page, making the actual contents buried deep down.

Luckily for me, I already have account and usually logged in. I don't see any of this clutter. But speaking on behalf of those who don't have account or not always logged in, can this login dialog be hidden by default and pop in only when clicking something, e.g. "Log In" or "Sign Up" buttons?

Comment: "Why did you make an account?" "To get rid of that gigantic banner and signup form."

Comment: @BoltClock yeah, like a door-to-door salesman who keeps nagging you to buy something until you have no choice but to buy it, so that he won't show up on your door every day. lol.

Comment: I can only feel sorry for you for having such a low resolution monitor....

Comment: @rene actually my monitor is big, SO is using fixed width. Wait...

Comment: I don't mean to defend this design (that gigantic banner is like taking a power-drill to the eyes), but if you already are able to log into SO, having a place to do so that's obvious, as well as strong indications that you're *not* logged in at present, is not a bad thing.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I think this feature request is meant to be read in the perspective of a user who doesn't yet have an account and isn't interested in making one. Perhaps Shadow Wizard should have made a sock puppet, suggested some bogus edits and posted this with the sock puppet, just to drive the point home (to the devs, of course, not you).

Comment: Call me a cynic, but I think all we can expect here is yet another "we need to keep the lights on" answer. /sigh

Comment: @yannis hard to believe. There are other ways to make people want to login.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, there are other ways. But the big blue box isn't really about getting people to log in to Stack Overflow, the Q&A site we know and love. It's bait-and-switch for Jobs. Try it and see.

Comment: That banner takes up 40% of the screen. It's UI basics 101 that you don't put huge banners that make users scroll down the screen to get to what they clicked for.

Comment: I can has expertsexchange.com?

Comment: @yannis omg, lol... so sad it's funny. But hey, at least they don't spam Jobs into people's email boxes just yet... so it can be worse.

Comment: this is absolutely only for [meta-tag:jobs] @yannis - you're right. I just checked guest mode at a bunch of other sites in the Stack Exchange network and none other has this offensive banner. Because Jobs are only for SO, no other sites have it and no other site shoots that banner into visitors face. No wonder that the rest of SE network gets now more views than SO, with a deterrent like that

Comment: @rene Just as bad at UHD https://imgur.com/a/qh0ZM ;p

Comment: Hey, at least it's not a giant full screen modal overlay with a tiiiny close icon in the top right corner that shows up after a timer. But yeah, that's pretty distracting.

Comment: @ivarni well there is such modal showing when trying to vote while not logged in but yeah, not with timer, I'll give them that. :)

Comment: @BoltClock this matter looks important enough to get a [meta-tag:featured] tag

Comment: This is the login screen that makes me re-log using my other account (accidentally) that triggers my other personality.

Comment: This is hilarious ;0

Comment: Agreed, this is really bad.

Comment: Agreed. I have my browser set up to auto-delete cookies whenever I close the browser (for security/privacy reasons), so I have to manually log in every day. Being confronted with this on a daily basis is fairly cringe worthy.

Comment: SO and the SE network is very bad at UX and UI.  I have posted 1000's of posts on meta in terms of the jobs site.  People laugh it off or close it as status-deferred or the BS about it supposedly being that way.  They need a good MANAGER in terms of UX/UI.  They don't believe in that, and this is the result.

Comment: @JonH to be honest, the rest is fine by me. I prefer minimalistic UX and until this... thing... had no issue with user experience on SO/SE. But this... this is worse than anything I could imagine.

Comment: I would love a blog post on how it actually got to this point. I mean, this is an excellent example of how small gradual changes led to a disastrous final outcome. IMO is a great case study on how it can happen.

Comment: This is offensive and self-destructive. Outside of some illegal download sites, I don't think I've encountered another web page that covered *three quarters* of the screen with advertising like this. Stack Overflow will lose the next generation of programmers if it stays this way; they'll come, see the advertising, and decide that Stack Overflow is a shady place that they should not return to.

Comment: @MarkAmery not really since there is no alternative. Programmers have no choice just yet. But once they will have a choice I totally agree, they will flee in terror.

Comment: @ShadowWizard you're assuming that an inexperienced programmer who doesn't know about Stack Overflow, upon seeing the hideous visage that awaits them when they click a Stack Overflow link on Google, will *even bother to read onwards* rather than assuming they've clicked through to some shady highly-SEOed spam site and picking another result from some more reputable-looking source (like any of the many Stack Overflow clones made by scraping all of its content). Okay, sure, at some point somebody's going to set them straight. But it's still a damaging first impression.

Comment: Folks, I think we have a perfect storm of testing all coming together in a way that I'm not at all certain is intentional to begin with. Please hang tight while I find out what's going on, and then I'll write a proper answer. Note, I can already see that vacation calendars are going to make this tricky, but let me see what I can find out.

Comment: Okay, note, changes are coming to this (first being making the banner smaller, second being changing how and when the 'new' thing is shown to anonymous users); _exact_ details of this will be in the fix for it and might take a day or two, at which time I'll know those exact details and (unsurprisingly) be able to explain them in a proper answer here. Hang tight.

Comment: @TimPost thanks, but I find it hard to believe it is part of "testing"... Judging from comments this is in place for a while now. Anyway better late than never, looking forward to see the changes.

Comment: The bait-and-switch part of this whole mess, which is the worst part really, is certainly [not due to testing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357463/google-login-button-on-home-page-goes-to-developer-story/357476#357476)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know testing is a factor here, what I don't know is to what extent, and why we didn't have more eyeballs going incognito to pick up on it sooner. The fact that we're working out what to do about it actually indicates that this wasn't the intentional outcome. I'll get all the wonderfully boring details written up as soon as we get it sorted.

Comment: I was under the impression that this was supposed to **only** be on the landing page for stackoverflow.com if you were not signed in.

Comment: Hmm... I thought it was decided to not use the new button in favor of just having a dialog? Now we're doing both?

Comment: "*No other site pushes so much useless content on each and every page, making the actual contents buried deep down.*" Someone has clearly never fallen victim to one of those *click-baity* sites - you know, the ones with titles like, "*First he did this! You won't believe what happened next...*" where you click **Next** fifty times to view the whole article that could easily have fit in the comments section.

Comment: @OhBeWise oh I have. Should have clarified by "No other legit/professional site" perhaps. :)

Comment: @Tim thanks. Expecting full report on my desk... oh wait, desk is cluttered. Never mind. ;-)

Comment: "No other site pushes so much useless content on each and every page, making the actual contents buried deep down." because most sites don't have any actual content. Have you visited Facebook, Buzzfeed...?

Comment: As somebody who uses SO on incognito sessions fairly often I think this has been here for at least a week or so, consistently about that bad. Even as somebody who knows there's about a 10% chance of finding the answer to 20% of the thing I'm searching for on SO (which is pretty decent considering the subject matter) I tend to get burned out on closing the darn "log in" thing twice and I just start skimming the summary on Google, or switching to other sites for content.

Comment: @djechlin see my previous comment: "No other legit / **professional** site". Facebook is anything but professional. Default assumption for anything posted there is that it's fake or just not true. Dunno about Buzzfeed, not familiar with the site.

Comment: The real question here is why SO keeps making ridiculous UI change after ridiculous UI change. Any other site without as much community feedback, repeatedly making superfluous or outright stupid changes like these, would have dug their own grave. Hire some designers with _common sense_ already.

Comment: @Lundin I suspect that's what they did: hiring UX experts, and that's the result. As Tim Post said, it's not what they originally meant, guess there was some major misunderstanding. For example, the CEO tells the  UX team something like "Let's have something to boost visits to Developer Story so that we can give some nice numbers to those who pay us so much". They are showing him that huge banner and he says "Awesome, do it!", meaning only in the main page, but not saying it directly. So they put it on all pages.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The problem is that they came up with the banner to begin with - that suggests a lack of common sense. Similarly, introducing ugly "monochrome blob" icons because "everyone else got them". Seems like they are just mindlessly following what UI trends that are fashionable at the moment. As for the CEO, I don't think he is involved in the company much...

Comment: @ShadowWizard although I hate what they did, I think that limiting banner to only main page is not an option, it likely has too low of a reach. SO main page is useless, showing banner there would be like not showing it at all

Comment: I agree. I think the big blue sign up banner is useless. If a user wants to sign up, they can use the Sign Up button in the top bar. If they don't, they probably don't want to sign up.

Comment: I agree this is terrible.  But a lot of you are saying "I've never seen any website THIS bad."  That's BS.  I've come across loads of websites with full sceen modal overlays, some of these pages you really have to work to see the content. lol Check out the Forbes website.

Comment: @CrazyPaste guess I'm spoiled then, or just forgot such horrible sites as I never visited them again. :)

Comment: It's almost as if StackOverflow is a well built and massively crowdsourced website which was designed to be a cash-cow from the get-go.

Comment: Numbers > People

Comment: My concern isn't really so much the cruft itself, but that SE corporate culture is now such that not only did someone come up with this idea in the first place, but then someone else said "yes, that's a good idea, let's do that". At _best_, the second part didn't happen, which would in turn mean that there is no review/testing for the very front page of the website. What does all this tell us, I wonder?

Comment: That being said, I agree with the commenters above who observe that there are much, much worse pages out there in the wild. Sadly, it seems, annoying "subscribe to my newsletter!" "accept my cookies!" "tell us what you think!" popups are back in fashion, just as JavaScript overlays rather than new windows. Yay.

Comment: @ShadowWizard okay, try linkedin.com or forbes.com.

Comment: We already have a pile full of "there are much worse sites out there" cards sitting on the table. We don't need more of you playing the same card over and over again. Be that guy who brings something *new* to the table.

Comment: Note that GitHub's major competitor currently [has no advertising banners on their repository pages](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape), just like Stack Overflow used to be the contrast to Experts Exchange. I'm a *huge* fan of GitLab, by the way, for their non-shady business practices and excellent service. Hopefully, if they end up unseating GitHub, they won't fall into the same shadiness that tends to befall market leaders. And look at that nice, svelte, well-organized topbar!

Comment: On a 1366x768 screen [it's still quite bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF2oF.png).

Comment: @jrh yeah, but at least only in the homepage, not every question page.

Comment: @ShadowWizard True, for question pages it's better, but still [not great](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYiEl.png).

Comment: This is even worse now they have added a sidebar on the left.

Comment: @JamesDouglas that is true. :(

Comment: See this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322749/make-it-easier-to-find-what-you-want

Answer (score 228):

I was about to defend some aspects of this, but fortunately I tried it out again in an incognito session, and it's actually much worse than I remember. I'm not sure if it changed in the meantime, is subject to A/B tests or if I simply didn't trigger the more annoying parts earlier.

My original impression is that this was only on the frontpage, for some reason I didn't see this on individual questions. But it's actually there on individual questions and on the frontpage, the only exception seems to be the Questions tab. So unless you dismiss it, this banner appears on every single question on the whole site.

This thing is dismissable, but only on the individual questions page, not on the frontpage. To make it worse, I missed that entirely at first because there is no "X" to dismiss on the frontpage, so I didn't really look for it later on the individual questions. But even then, the huge banner on the frontpage stays permanently, there is no way to remove it without signing up.

Now, once you dismissed it, you get another smaller banner nagging you to sign up on individual question pages. You can dismiss this as well, but really, I just dismissed the annoying big brother of that message, do you really have to force me to dismiss the small version manually as well?

The original idea of Stack Overflow was to maximize the signal-to-noise ratio, remove all the fluff present in most forums, and concentrate on the actual content. This header adds a whole lot of noise, but not really any signal.

Comment: Thanks for the support! As for its "little brother", it's probably the same banner we get on all other SE sites, and with that I'm actually kind of fine. But that huge banner is really over any possible edge.

Comment: @ShadowWizard My point is mostly that the banner appears directly after I dismissed a banner with the same content. I shouldn't have to dismiss this twice.

Comment: Sure, but that's probably worth a separate request or even bug report.

Comment: Yeah, it kinda puts the whole "we need to remove 'Thanks!' and other clutter from the questions and answers" into perspective, eh?

Comment: > My original impression is that this was only on the frontpage


Well, the frontpage is a little worse. Notice the additional horizontal bar (Stack Overflow Business Solutions) : https://i.imgur.com/ZcCInC2.jpg

Comment: Reduce to a small banner that encourages signing up by sharing... I'm also a fan of a pulsing "new" button to be honest. Really pop the flare. Showoff some creativity. Use the mac genie suck affect via html5 when they go off page load.

Answer (score 143):

I tried this under incognito mode since I thought it could be that the OP's resolution was too low or something. This is what I see with a 1920x1080 resolution 23'' monitor.

[image]

The actual space given to the answer at first sight is <s>~5%</s> (I forgot that zoom settings were kept under incognito mode) ~28% of the SO frame and ~14% of the entire screen. That's bad.

Comment: Remember that site where you used to have to scroll all the way down to the very bottom of the page, past a bunch of advertising, in order to find the answer you came for? Hmm....

Comment: @CodyGray: Are your really comparing SO to Expert Sex Change? Or what site are you referring to?

Comment: Even zoomed in, the point still stands – if the site needs to be zoomed in to be usable (which is an issue in its own right), then that's what criticism should be based on.

Comment: @lxg I think his point was, shoving other things in your face invites comparison with that site. The similarity is considerable.  If "it's not nearly as bad as expertsexchange" isn't damning with faint praise, I'm not sure what would be.

Comment: @jthill indeed. SO used to be a whole league above EE. Now with this horrible UX they are in the same league and only the quality content "save" it.

Comment: a.k.a. "we hired too many people to build banners so we need more banners to pay their salaries". It's a trap!

Comment: @ShadowWizard  One banner that requires tweaks (a lot of tweaks imho) doesn't mean the entire UI is bad my friend. It's really well designed, clean simple, lighweight and gets constant improvements. You wanna see bad UI that You actually pay to experience - go visit Amazon or Ebay :-)

Comment: And that's on a screen with a high resolution. On my laptop, the space given to the answer is 3% of the SO frame and 2% of the screen (and that's without turning off AdBlock).

Comment: @Skipper that's one banner that is showing in every single page and hiding every single piece of content. So yeah, that's about the entire UI.

Comment: At least SO isn't [selling you a timeshare](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103662/how-to-survive-a-timeshare-promotional-trip).

Comment: @MichaelGeary not yet. ;)

Comment: "Not as bad as someotherbunchofshysters.com" isn't really a very good argument for keeping it the way it is.

Comment: @CodyGray Looks like Expert Sex Change.com is up for sale. Know any good doctors looking to pay out the nose for a parked domain?

Comment: @Monkey The real site uses a hyphen in its name... Still kicking. The total lack of content on the home page is distressingly familiar, though.

Comment: @CodyGray Yep, I noticed that. I honestly cannot remember if they've had the hyphen since the beginning though...

Comment: @CodyGray maybe hyphenated site looks differently for logged-in users, just like it is now with Stack Overflow

Answer (score 59):

Okay, let me be clear. This big ass sign up hero was a bad idea. I was responsible for this decision and want to apologize to our community. This month we will be testing a few smaller designs that we hope will still encourage people to sign up without taking over their screens. Our goal is to test these designs and push one of them live before the end of the month.

**A bit of background:** In an attempt to move quickly and make improvements (inline sign up) we  pushed this huge sign up hero for our anonymous users. We did it first on the home page, where I think the design is appropriate. As we shifted to updating the hero for the Question page,  we got focused on a technical challenge. We needed to make it light weight enough that it wouldn't hurt perf on the question page which accounts for the vast majority of our page views. As the focus shifted to this challenge, I never really asked, "Is this a good idea? Is the right design for this experience?"

Once the perf problem was solved, we ran an A/B experiment it and I got excited by the huge gains that the new hero showed (~60% gains) So, we pushed it live. Those huge gains didn't hold up, but they were still significant (low double digits). However, it became clear that these weren't necessarily "good" sign ups. We weren't seeing the right level of engagement post sign-up. This data along with this community feedback was enough to make us reconsider the approach.

Thanks for being direct, honest and constructive in your feedback.

Comment: I'm always direct and honest, trying hard to be constructive as well. Thanks for the detailed reply!

Answer (score 16):

Looking at your screen shot I think that if SE team would want to have a maximal possible reach for [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) without jeopardising providing users desired content they could put a banner at [sidebar](/questions/tagged/sidebar), about like as follows:

[image: annoying jobs banner at sidebar]

This would somewhat compromise job ads that currently occupy the suggested place (for anonymous users only because logged in ones will see job ads as they do now, because of disabled banner).

But I somehow feel like recovery of views and reputation lost because of current sub-optimal banner location would compensate for that minor loss.

Comment: That's certainly an improvement.

Comment: definitely **not** in that color scheme... It kills my eyes.

Comment: this is more of a desperate idea @NathanArthur - as soon as I realised that it's unlikely to completely get jobs spam off the questions page (for the reasons of audience reach and... shall we say extremely strong desire to monetize content) I started thinking of how it would be possible to minimize its damage. In a perfect world there would be no banner at all

Comment: If this idea ever sees the light of day then maybe "GET JOB HERE!" could be below the HNQ?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I wouldn't be surprised if they do this because HNQ is also a big business with [about 100K clicks a day](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6304786#6304786) :)

Comment: gnat: what's "*HNQ*"?

Comment: @DavidThomas HNQ stands for Hot Network Questions - [meta-tag:hot-questions]