# New sign up hero for question pages

Tags: discussion, announcement

We've updated the sign up [hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_image) that anonymous users see on all question pages. It is now a more subtle bar at the bottom of the window. There was a bunch of on point criticism of the prior version as being too big, too annoying and obscuring the most important content. ([See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357858/dont-clutter-half-the-screen-with-things-most-people-dont-care-for/359008)).

### New version

[image: New version; sign up hero on the bottom of Stack Overflow]

### Previous version

[image: Old version; sign up hero at the top of Stack Overflow]

### A bit of background

In an attempt to move quickly and make improvements (inline sign up) we pushed this huge sign up hero for our anonymous users. We did it first on the home page, where I think the design is appropriate. As we shifted to updating the hero for the Question page, we got focused on a technical challenge. We needed to make it light weight enough that it wouldn't hurt performance on the question page which accounts for the vast majority of our page views. As the focus shifted to this challenge, I never really asked, "Is this a good idea? Is the right design for this experience?"

Once the performance problem was solved, we ran an A/B experiment it and I got excited by the huge gains that the new hero showed (~60% gains) So, we pushed it live. Those huge gains didn't hold up, but they were still significant (low double digits).

However, it became clear that these weren't necessarily "good" sign ups. We weren't seeing the right level of engagement post sign-up. This data along with this community feedback was enough to make us reconsider the approach and make the above change.

Comment: Are non-web designers supposed to know what a "hero" is?

Comment: I am afraid, that Stack Overflow employees are falling victim to selection bias. Neither this one or previous banners are any good. A bunch of shiny, magenta-indigo-orange-red-yellow-colored  stuff with offer to "register for amazing goodies"? This is a tell-tale sign of porn/fraud site to avoid. If that stuff have been there, when I started using Stack Overflow back then, I probably would have *never* registered. What kind of registered users are you trying to acquire with such approach?

Comment: @m69 I've never heard the term before in this usage, but upon seeing the post, i'm about 80% sure that a Hero is the stuff that pops up on screens of people who aren't logged in to give them the option to sign in or sign up. Would someone like to correct that assumption?

Comment: *mumbles something about lack of [freehand red circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775)...* Seriously though, thank you!

Comment: @m69 it's what Bonny Tyler's been holding out for until the end of the night? ;)

Comment: @user1643723 it is probably important to keep in mind that this stuff attempts to attract users to register at [meta-tag:jobs], not at Stack Overflow (whatever kind users they get registered at jobs, I honestly don't care because it's not Stack Overflow)

Comment: This looks like a reasonable compromise between "public" interest (having a freely accessible question & answer archive) and business interest (maximizing the number of registered users for Jobs and other shenanigans).

Comment: I'd argue that you've replaced the "Hero" with a "Call to action" (I knowz the lingoz)... I little bit of me just died.

Comment: Good. Hero images should die a fast death. I don't care whether big site X uses it or whether popular UX blogger Y blogged about it, they're annoying as hell and take away screen estate for nothing.

Comment: There is still so much garbage on the site. Thankfully adblockers make quick work of it.

Comment: You missed a spot (the front page still has the huge obtrusive and confusing version). I know it's on purpose. And I never use SO logged out. It just irks me to know it's there.

Comment: *“Email sign up or sign in with Google / Facebook”* – Are those *sign in* with Google or Facebook really sign-ins? I remember something about last time where this prompted you to create a new account and this wasn’t an actual login for existing users.

Comment: `s/sign-up hero/sign-up prompt/g` to make the post more readable for non web developers… (and less eye twitching for people who know that the new thing is *not* a hero banner…)

Comment: "build your career". Whoa there, the truth is more that you don't break your career ;) The building part you still have to do all on your own.

Comment: @m69 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_image

Comment: @poke AFAIK, technically an account will be created automatically when you use OAuth (Google/Facebook). You don't get password (for email sign-in) to sign in unless you add a new login to it.

Comment: @AndrewT. I can’t find the exact comment in the old thread right now, just [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357858/dont-clutter-half-the-screen-with-things-most-people-dont-care-for/359008#comment522866_357858), but from what I remember, I think people said that clicking log in there with an existing account would lead them to jobs instead of staying on QA.

Comment: Would signing up be heroic enough to be awarded the "upsigned hero" badge?

Answer (score 58):

## Thank you.

Seeing a giant banner at the top of Stack Overflow while I had the displeasure of being signed out at work (for legitimate reasons) was probably one of the most frustrating things I've seen.  I'm extremely happy that this change has been taken on board.

That said, I do hope that this also means that the amount of "good" sign-ups increases substantially.

Comment: I think your "Thank you" is too subtle, I suggest you make it larger and CAPITALS...

Answer (score 30):

**This is a welcome change! Kudos :)**

But the banner seems to be hindering the website footer:

[image]

Thus partially hiding some of the footer elements and links. I can see the banner is some kind of an overlay, though clicking [x] resolves it.

---

I hope the same change might get implemented(in the near future) for the SO Homepage's banner.

Comment: Oh wait, there's a footer on this site?

Answer (score -5):

**It is nice to see a clean page rather than a giant blocking me screen.**

The footer could be made transparent to see the footer or more fluid and stays on one part of the screen. Also, the Stack Exchange login could also be enabled.