# Why is the option of signing up easier to find on the homepage than logging in?

Tags: discussion, design, homepage

Why is it that the sign-up button is easier to identify on the home page  than login? Is it due to the fact that there are more non-registered users using the site than registered ones?

[image: Stack Overflow homepage]

Comment: I'd say that since the fact that most users auto-login, this is certainly logical. I believe I've only manually logged in 3-4 times in the lifetime of my account.

Comment: It already much improved with that giant hero banner [only on the homepage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357858/dont-clutter-half-the-screen-with-things-most-people-dont-care-for).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  hadn't considered auto-login. It does make more sense. But you'd still have to click on the login page to reach it unless there is a book mark.

Comment: @RavindraHV Nope, cookies. Don't have to click anything, I'm just always logged in.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I guess SO developers would do well do implement CSRF tokens (unless they already have) for all user actions if its a popular choice as you say. Thanks!

Comment: @rene That particular post says the big banner is not good and my point is similar - the focus appears to be to encourage registration - neither giving a new user an option to search nor helping potential registered users ask queries or answer them (by making it easier to login - for those who do not do auto-login). I guess most users are from search engines and google's may be better than SO's search engine itself but that only means there is scope for improvement in this regard.

Comment: The point of that other post was that the banner used to be on *ALL* pages for not signed in users. So on every question page you had that huge thing in your face if you  weren't logged in.

Comment: @rene Now there appears to be a side-kick (footer) banner for the other pages although it appears to be smart enough not to bother too many times. But I guess the site has a work in progress.

Comment: It's a common problem for many popular web-sites UI. I don't know why they do it. Take a look at [github](https://github.com/). I was totally sure the form on the right means a login one! [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/) is same as SO with "signup". On [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) it's hard to even find __any__ login button. Of course it does _not_ justify the problem for SO - but at least SO isn't alone in this.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a very common thing found on many web sites that they are optimized for the first-time visitor rather than the frequent visitor. One assumes it's by design; and although irritating, there is some logic to it -- frequent visitors know how to find their way around.

Comment: Agree with Michael Kay, I've noticed this behavior is becoming pretty standard across all web sites these days...

Comment: @AlmaDo TBH, if you try to sign up for Circle with an account you’ve already signed up with, it’ll sign you in. Travis does the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

As [Erik von Asmuth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-von-asmuth) mentioned, the default home page is more likely to be shown for ones that don't already have a Stack Overflow account.

Plus, if a site wants to gain more traction and attract new users, it's more likely that it will highlight the sign up section instead of the login page, simply because it is fiscally benefical.

Comment: as far as I understand this sign up doesn't help Stack Overflow gain more traction and attract new users because it is for a different site (for [meta-tag:jobs])

Comment: Some websites go so far with this that it's really hard to find the login page. Sometimes you have to click "sign up" to find the login page. I think SO are doing quite a good job here.

Comment: @gnat jobs isn't a separate site anymore, it is merged with so unfortunately.

Comment: Agreed. Additionally, a relatively niche site know as [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/) seems to follow this pattern as well.