# Repeated "Sign up" options

Tags: discussion, design, sign-up

While browsing a question (when **not** being logged-in), I am greeted with this "Login / Sign Up" banner at the bottom, which looks *okay-ish* (when there already exists a login/signup in the header itself):

[image]

---

After dismissing the banner, another one shows up (which looks fine):

[image]

---

I am no design or UX expert by any means, but is this "Sign up" button

[image]

actually necessary to be shown? It looks repetitive IMHO.

Comment: I guess they *really* want you to sign up.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen This is just like how Microsoft used to push Windows 10!

Comment: "list" appears four times in the title of that question - which is one more than the number of "Sign up" buttons on the page. O_o

Comment: I'd also question the colon at the end of the second banner, seeing as what comes after is a load of white space, followed by a button. But that's just a minor nitpick!

Comment: I'm more bothered that the second banner button says "Sign up" instead of "Sign Up".

Comment: Is the second banner actually necessary at all? The page says "Hey, sign up!", and you say "no", but the page says "Hey, sign up" again and in a totally different place!

Comment: FYI you can [sign up for Stack Overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup).

Comment: Just so you folks don't forget what @JF said, you can [Sign up for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup) here.

Answer (score 4):

The banner you see at the bottom of your screen is an attempt at fixing [this problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357858/4909087). Considering what it once was (an unpalatably large hero banner), I see this as an improvement. At least it isn't in your face anymore.

One thing I *do* have a problem with, is this:

[image]

The `u` in the `up` part of `Sign up` is in lower case in the button below, but uppercase in the one above. If nothing else, I'd at least hope to see some case consistency here (to quell my OCD of course...).

Comment: Two _similar_ buttons in the same vicinity, doing the same work is absolutely barbaric! One must die.

Comment: @o_O Well, it either needs fixing (the case, I mean), or deleting... something has to happen.

Comment: My OCD is kicking in also.  I also think someone should put all other tasks aside and FIX THIS ISSUE NOW!